# Async Await with moongose node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I got a issue with es6 async/await while working on below code. The problem is if there is any error occurred during saving it is not throwing any error (like i have validation on password and using try/catch), So do i need to use promise then/catch or is there any way with this?

```
 try {

        var response = {response_code:1,response_message:"success",response_obj:[]};
        var statusCode =200;
        if(true) {
            const {f_name, mail, social_id, via, l_name} = req.body;


            const existUser = await User.findOne({$or: [{email: mail}]});

            if (existUser != null) {
                var err = new Error("User Already Exists");
                err.status  = 400;
                throw err;
            }
            const ref_id =   await  UserUtils.makeRefId();
            const verification_code =  UserUtils.generateVerificationCode();

            var newUser = new User({
                firstname : f_name,
                lastname  : l_name,
                password : "dsadasdas",
                social:{social_id : social_id,
                             via : via},
                email : mail,
                ref_id : ref_id,
                verification_code : verification_code,
                role :"USER",
                loc: {type: "Point", coordinates: [0, 0]},
                provider: 'local',
            });


            const data =  await newUser.save(); //its not throwing any error

            console.log(data);
        }
        else
        {
            const err = new Error("Please Send Required Parameters");
            err.status =  400;
            throw  err;
        }
    }catch(err){
        statusCode  = err.status;
        response.response_code = 0;
        response.response_message = err.message;
    }
    finally
    {
        return res.status(statusCode).json(response);
    }
```

Comment: if you're going to use async/await then I think you need to use the old try/catch

Comment: I am using try/catch but no error is generating

Comment: in the code you posted you are **not** using try/catch - perhaps you're doing something wrong in the code you say you use try/catch in

Comment: try/catch are above this code i tried the save method using promise then/catch method and it is generating error

Comment: if the try/catch is "above this code" then it's in the wrong place to catch any error in this code - try/catch isn't psychic, it doesn't know what you mean, it does what you write

Comment: you haven't shown nearly enough code to show what you are doing wrong

Comment: Why are you using `newUser.saveAsync()`? Use `await newUser.save()`

Comment: i also tried await with simple save() mehtod

Comment: You need to `await` promises so that you catch errors in them. Of course, when the promises don't reject, then you also won't get an exception.

Comment: i got the problem it was in my catch because i was using error object and i have to throw the error object in it